# Blinking dashed link

Tags: css

I'd like to ask if there is a solution for a little inconvenience I've encountered with a dashed links.

To save your time here is an example of my code, upon hovering specifically on a *dashed line* underneath an actual link it starts blinking immensely and it is not very aesthetically appealing. I'm fairly new into the css so I wonder if there is a mistake in my code.

```
p {
    font-size: 35px;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#ff0089;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom-color: #ff0089;
    border-bottom-width: 2px;
    border-bottom-style: dashed;
    -o-transition:color .2s ease-out, background 1s ease-in;
    -ms-transition:color .2s ease-out, background 1s ease-in;
    -moz-transition:color .2s ease-out, background 1s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition:color .2s ease-out, background 1s ease-in;
    transition:color .2s ease-out, background 1s ease-in;
}
a:hover {
    color:#eae327;
    background: none;
    border-bottom-style: none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/j86ba/

Much obliged.

Comment: strange, I don't see any blinking by me. Which browser blinks?

Comment: Chrome, but I also have checked in FF, although in FF it blinks with a less frequency. It starts to blink when you hover exactly on a dashed line.

Comment: No issue my end `Chrome 31 on Linux`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because the border disappears on hover - turning of the hover functionality. So then the line reappears making in `onHover` again... (loop)

The solution I found was to set the `color` to `white` (or, whatever your background may be) instead of setting `style` to `none`. (I tried setting `width` to `0`, but it had the same effect).

[See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j86ba/1/)

Seems hackish, but it works...

**I would add** that the probability of a user actually hovering exactly on the line (which triggers this behavior) is unlikely and probably shouldn't worry you. i.e. see comments on the question where people who were actually trying to make it happen couldn't reproduce the issue.

Comment: Hackish or not, works for me perfectly. Much, much appreciated, friend.

Comment: Yes, I haven't been noticing this for quite a time myself, but you must know the feeling when there is _something wrong_ and even though it doesn't have a considerable impact it still disturbs you because you know it is there :)

Answer (score 0):

JNF's answer is good or you can hack by using this too in your anchor style :

```
display: inline-block;
height: 40px;
```